# KeywordModel accesing metadata

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

We need to access metadata fields in our keywords. We realised that in the master branch of the dxa-web-application-java project, there's already a KeywordModel that will solve this issue in previous dxa versions. So we added the needed classes into our project.

However, when debugging I realised that we are not mapping the keyword info in our model because the extensionData is null. Do we need to upload the TBBs?

```
private String getMetadataSchemaId(Keyword keyword) {
            if (keyword.getExtensionData() == null ||
                    !keyword.getExtensionData().containsKey("DXA") ||
                    !keyword.getExtensionData().get("DXA").getContent().containsKey("MetadataSchemaId")) {
                return null;
            }

            return (String) keyword.getExtensionData().get("DXA").getContent().get("MetadataSchemaId").getValues().get(0);
    }
```

Comment: It does look like it depends on a change to the TBBs indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DXA 1.7 story regarding KeywordModel is still in progress. Indeed, the Java implementation is not complete yet.

Furthermore, the story indeed also requires CM-side changes (see commits on the `dxa-content-management` repository).

Note that DXA 1.7 is scheduled for release end of this year.